# Should a boolean flag always be atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Suppose there is a boolean flag (**keep_running**) which is controlled by the main thread. Another thread loops indefinitely until this flag becomes false.

```
int main() {
    bool keep_running(true);
    std::thread run( [](bool &keep_running)
    {
        while(keep_running)
        {
            // do work
        }
    }, std::ref(keep_running) );

    // do other work
    keep_running = false;
    run.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Should that flag be atomic?

```
std::atomic<bool> keep_running
```

I imagine, the worst which can happen to the non-atomic version would be that the flag gets set right at the time when the

```
while(keep_running)
```

is executed. In which case, the loop keeps running for one more (not strictly needed) iteration. But in my case, this would be acceptable.

Is there a possible scenario where the above code could be wrong?

EDIT:

I'm mostly interested in this for performance reasons (and for not having bugs). Thus, would the use of std::atomic for the flag in the loop negatively impact performance?

Comment: In elder versions of C++, you would have used `volatile` - without it, there's a possibility that the write to the variabile from one thread will not be seen from the other thread. But, since in C++11 there's `atomic`, you should use that to prevent the same issue.

Comment: Of course it should be atomic. That gives you the correct semantics. Why would you want to do anything else?

Comment: I was thinking, I neither do need a memory barrier around the flag nor would I care about instruction reordering. Therefore, I thought I could get rid of the std::atomic to gain performance. I tried to clarify that by editing the question. But I didn't realize the variable could be stuck in the registers, as pointed out by Tsyvarev in his answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just C++11 standard which forbids (mark them as **Undefined Behaviour**) concurrent accesses to non-atomic variable.

So you need to declare this variable atomic.

Note, that using `keep_running.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`  for read value and `keep_running.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed)` for write value will eliminate any additional perfomance costs, so resulted code will be as faster as one without atomic.

---

> I imagine, the worst which can happen to the non-atomic version would be that the flag gets set right at the time.

It can be happen that in your thread the variable will be stored into register and never be reloaded (so thread will never be stopped). Without `atomic` or other special type and modifiers compiler is allowed to do that, and it actually does.

Comment: I would upvote but think the statement "The worst which can be happen is that the variable will be stored into register in your thread and never be reloaded" is misleading. The worst that could happen is anything at all in regards to UB. Te compiler could do anything whatsoever in response to it including a failure at any point in the program. Please add a note of this and this would be an excellent answer.

Comment: The post begins with notion about UB and that it is *forbidden* by the standard. I see no needs to repeat that at the end, in the informative part. But I have removed words "the worst", so it is just one of possible *bad* scenarios, not the only one.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect, I didnt mean that it should be repeated, just that it would not be good into having the OP think that was the only ill effect that might happen which "the worst" seemed to +1

Comment: Disagree with ' will eliminate any additional perfomance costs'. Not true on non-cache coherent systems.

Comment: @SergeyA: How generated code for non-atomic(but in-memory) and relaxed atomic accesses differs on non-cache coherent systems?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, simple enough - on non-coherent systems atomic writes, even relaxed, have to propagate to all CPUs, while regular writes do not have to go anywhere but local cache. On cache-coherent systems it is the same, of course. Actually, if not for non-cache coherent systems, there would be actually no reason to have relaxed memory model to begin with - simple volatile would do.

Comment: Hmm, are common C++ programs used on non-cache coherent architectures? I have failed to google any evidence for this. E.g., [here](http://lse.sourceforge.net/numa/faq/index.html#numa_v_ccnuma) they said that `The applications for non-cache coherent NUMA machines are almost non-existent, and they are a real pain to program for`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You would have to predict the future to answer that question usefully. Programs we write today may be in use on CPUs that do not yet exist. One of the reasons that we have language standards is so that you don't have to worry about CPU changes.